# How to choose individual lines in merge conflicts with GitHub extension for Visual Studio

Tags: git, merge, visual-studio-2017

I am using [GitHub extension for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.github.com/) whenever I want to merge two branches and get conflicts sometimes the extension decides certain lines of code can replace others and I am presented with only a single checkbox, either from the source or target but not both. I.e. I can only choose to replace that line of code or not, I cannot keep both.

How can I keep both without doing it manually for each line?

For example in the image below I'd like to have the result code of

```
List<Label> LabelsC = new List<Label>();
List<Label> LabelsCO2 = new List<Label>();
```

[image]

Comment: merging in VS you have 2 parts of screen: source, target and result. You can just edit result how you want, for example take part from source, part from target and even write something manually.

Comment: see screenshot: https://osnabrugge.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/image_thumb9.png

Comment: @Alexan, well now I feel stupid - I saw I can't edit the top two windows but never tried the result one.

Comment: @Alexan, still on big merges doing every line by hand is troublesome - any way to tell VS "resolve this conflict by moving this one after the other"?

Comment: you can choose code from target and source both, which one will be top or bottom depends which checkbox I press first.

Comment: @Alexan, but sometimes there is a line of code that overlaps another and I am not presented with the option to choose the one from, for example source, so if I want to have both lines I have to do it manually.

Comment: so you can choose both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153296/discussion-between-mathgenius-and-alexan).

Answer (score 3):

You have three options while merging.

1. You can select one checkbox you want to keep. It can be on both side. (You can choose your code or remote code.)
2. You can also select both checkbox. In this case, your code will be appended to remote code. This append operations will be based on your line number.
3. You can also change your code while merging. There is seperate tab below both your and remote tab which shows final output after merging. You also can edit that code and do line operations.

Actually this is perfect work flow as per git rules. All merge operations are embedded in VS. I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egy2r6ReaeI) video might help you.

Comment: There is no checkbox on the right. -_-          It's right in the screenshot, man.

Comment: There must be a checkbox on right. It is in vs 2015 for sure. May be you are making mistake while merging operation.

Comment: Making a mistake on the merging operation? Like what - clicking the "Merge" button the wrong way around? :) VS just thinks those two lines of code are equivalent - it think one is a direct "upgrade" to the other. I need to tell him he better wisen up but I can't find the button for it.